# declare or convert a string to array format PHP

Tags: php, string, arrays

How to convert a string format into an array format?

I have a string, `$string = 'abcde'`

I want to convert it to a 1 element array

```
$string[0] = 'abcde'
```

Is there a built in function for this task? Or the shortest way is to

```
$string = 'abcde';
$array[0] = $string;
$string = $array;
```

TIA

Comment: What do you mean by string "format" and array "format"? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think you need to update your tags to describe what programming language you're using.

Comment: Sorry, it is in php

What I am trying to do is that I have a variable name that I am using to store a return value from a function, the value can either be a string or an array.  I don't want to run an "if (is_array($string))" statement later on to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All kinds of ways in php..

```
$array = array('abcde');

$array[] = 'abcde';
```

Etc... not too sure what you're going for.

Edit: Oh, I think you might want to convert the first variable? Like this?

```
//Define the string
$myString = 'abcde';

//Convert the same variable to an array
$myString = array($myString);
```

Edit 2: Ahh, your comment above I think clears it up a little. You're getting back either an array or a string and don't know which. If you do what I just said above, you might get an array inside an array and you don't want that. So cast instead:

```
$someReturnValue = "a string";
$someReturnValue = (array)$someReturnValue;
print_r($someReturnValue);

//returns
Array
(
    [0] => a string
)


$someReturnValue = array("a string inside an array");
$someReturnValue = (array)$someReturnValue;
print_r($someReturnValue);

//returns
Array
(
    [0] => a string inside an array
)
```

Comment: You could use the (array) cast. Going to edit the answer to show you.

Comment: Great, I will keep the second part of your answer in mind.  The first part actually saved me a bunch of if condition codes.

Answer (score 0):

Lets not forget the standard way of declaring a string as an array in PHP, before adding elements..

```
$string = array();
```